# bifincan-web.log(Permission denied)

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu

I have my tomcat installed on an ubuntu server. I copied my application from my local server to my ubuntu server. But when  I run the application, I get the following error:

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: bifincan-web.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:142)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:290)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:194)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:164)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:257)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:285)
```

I have no clue what is wrong! The same application is running on my local tomcat.
I also tried running the tomcat as a super user by giving sudo -s

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: [understanding linux file permissions.](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions)

The user running tomcat doesn't have write permission in the directory where the logs are supposed to be written. And the solution is not to run tomcat as root! It's to change the permissions with chmod or chown.

Comment: Thanks Kayaman for the response, I did change all the permissions of all the possible places where tomcat can look into.  I also failed to find bifincan-web.log which it is referring to anywhere in the filesystem. I ran the following command: find . -name bifincan-web.log

Comment: You can't find the file because you didn't have permissions to create it. The file doesn't exist. Find the logging directory and set its permissions properly.